# Has Facebook replaced the fb_ref parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This morning I found out that Facebook is not returning the **fb_ref** parameter when you add it to links in actions or likes. Instead they seem to have replaced it with a series of new parameters: action_ref_map, action_object_map, ...

Could someone confirm me this change? This is breaking our software.

EDIT

This is an example that I've found:

```
http://uk.omg.yahoo.com/news/john-travoltas-year-gay-affair-pilot-revealed-122446486.html?fb_action_ids=10151047496853334&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map={%2210151047496853334%22%3A10151788645595106}&action_type_map={%2210151047496853334%22%3A%22news.reads%22}&action_ref_map={%2210151047496853334%22%3A%22type%3Aread%2Cuser%3A1k-WK59_Yk-EnPq2w1zMLBjX7nA%22}&code=AQCH-sq6XRSQCXj4QNkKlnusWLgIvBaZduNhGO0RNdiXgfCSGUOd1qinfHVw1iFQfs-0KVxFdPpWXD9nWrjEC1naU87H5W4GnxnTPL5j2raksea2pFxuy0rtgSpAa6ExZYCc7PkzIyjNnGTdK6N7g0Spb7qiqSboTgWZOojQJYbEF2XHenlROjhP8--NkvzrxU8#_=_
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems that Facebook has activated a new system for returning "fb_ref" in sandboxed FB apps.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fb_source/ is (and should be) the primary source of referral information and open graph actions have always had their own referral parameters showing which actions were present in the story/aggregation which triggered the click

fb_ref is provided when you had a 'ref' parameter on the source publish but as far as i know there hasn't been a change there

(e.g. like button with ref = foo results in a click back to your app with fb_ref=foo, fb_source=ticker or something like that)

Comment: We are using the ref parameter but instead of fb_ref in the resulting url we got all this news parameters that are not documented. I'm looking like crazy for information about Facebook changing this things  and found nothing. But I've found link from  18 hours ago more or less that has the new parameters.

Comment: you're using the 'ref' parameter in what? are these open graph objects or feed stories?

Comment: Sorry Igy, I'm using ref for open graph object/actions where I "want" a url to a page with og tags.

Comment: Unfortunately the FB documentation is pretty poor.